# Complementary events and conditioning

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If we have two events, $A$ and $B$, it is sure that

$$P(A\mid B) + P(A^C\mid B) = 1$$

However, it seems me that

$P(A\mid B) + P(A \mid B^C) = 1$ is false in general

I don't remember why it is so. How can this fact be explained in the simplest way?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram and contemplate it briefly.

Comment: Consider the case where A is the proposition "true", which always has a probability of 100%. Consider the case where it is instead the proposition "false", which always has a probability of 0%. So your sum can have a value anywhere from 0 to 2.

Comment: Think carefully about A="I win the lottery", B = "it rains the day I buy the ticket", for both the first and second scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need is just one counterexample.

Consider $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}$ with $P(\{1\}) = P(\{2\}) = P(\{3\}) = \frac{1}{3}$, $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{2, 3\}$, then

\begin{align}
& P(A|B) = \frac{P(\{2\})}{P(\{2, 3\})} = \frac{1/3}{2/3} = \frac{1}{2}, \\
& P(A|B^c) = \frac{P(\{1\})}{P(\{1\})} = \frac{1/3}{1/3} = 1,
\end{align}
which results in $P(A|B) + P(A|B^c) = \frac{3}{2} > 1$.

Another more extreme counterexample is for any sample space $\Omega$, take $A = \Omega$, and $B$ be any event with $0 < P(B) < 1$, then $P(A|B) + P(A|B^c) = 1 + 1 = 2 > 1$.

---

More in-depth analysis:  As you used the notation $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|B^c)$, which are meaningless unless $0 < P(B) < 1$, it can be assumed that $0 < P(B) < 1$. Under this condition,
\begin{align}
& P(A|B) + P(A|B^c) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} + \frac{P(A \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} = 1 \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
if and only if
\begin{align}
P(A \cap B)P(B^c) + P(A \cap B^c)P(B) = P(B)P(B^c). \tag{1}
\end{align}
If $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, then $(1)$ implies $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$.  Hence for any event $A$ whose probability is not $\frac{1}{2}$, the statement $(*)$ is false.

If $P(B) \neq \frac{1}{2}$, let $p := \max(P(B), P(B^c))$. Hence the left-hand side of $(1)$ is bounded above by $pP(A)$ and below by $(1 - p)P(A)$, $(1)$ thus implies that $pP(A) \geq p(1 - p) \geq (1 - p)P(A)$ or $P(A) \in [1 - p, p]$, which means that for any event $A$ whose probability is outside $[p, 1 - p]$, $(*)$ is false.

$(*)$ is not always false, of course. For example, if $\Omega = A \cup B$, $A \cap B = \varnothing$, then $A = B^c$, whence
\begin{align}
P(A|B) + P(A|B^c) = P(A|B^c) = \frac{P(B^c)}{P(B^c)} = 1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 10):

The conditional probability that you don't have red hair, given that you are male, is more than $0.9.$

The conditional probability that you don't have red hair, give that you are **not** male, is more than $0.9.$

The sum of those two probabilities is not $1.$

Answer (score 3):

To see why $P(A\mid B) + P(A \mid B^C) = 1$ is not generally true, consider the case where $A$ is always guaranteed to happen, regardless of what happens with $B$. Then both $P(A \mid B)$ and $P(A \mid B^{C})$ are equal to $1$, so you obtain $2=1$.